# How often do the arxiv moderators reclassify submissions?

Tags: arxiv

I submitted my first paper on arxiv and my submission is currently "on hold." I'm guessing this happened because of the category I chose. In the second to last page where I chose my category, there was an automated category that was chosen for me from an arxiv machine. I chose to dismiss this recommendation and keep the one I manually put in. My question is how long will the "on hold" status take and how often does arxiv reclassify submissions? Have any of you experienced something similar to this?

Comment: I'm guessing it is "on hold" for another reason, there are many. It'll take as long as it takes. This is common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user2768 points out, we can't know exactly why your article is on hold.

However, there could be several reasons: proper classification, pending moderator approval, presentation issues, copyrighted PDF, etc., to editorial concerns. Sometimes due to [oversized submission](https://arxiv.org/help/sizes). You may want to look at [arXiv submission status](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_status#:%7E:text=to%20incomplete%20status.-,On%20Hold,etc.%2C%20to%20editorial%20concerns.). You can try reaching to arXiv moderators if you need to enquire about this.

As you are asking about experience with long on-hold status: Yes, I have experienced once this status for over 45 days. Note that, I didn't bother asking them either. They automatically posted it in subsequent announcement. But this was more than 2 years ago.

Comment: Was this before the arxiv category classifier was implemented (May 20, 2020) or was this after?

Comment: It's before @kdf. I would suggest: just write to the arxiv moderation, they are very prompt in replying.

Comment: The category classifier has actually been in use _as a moderation tool_ since at least 2015.  Submissions where the classifier disagrees with the author's choice of subject are flagged for human moderation, which means they aren't announced until a moderator approves them for their category. (I was a moderator from 2007 to 2019.)

Comment: @JeffE Just a curious question; how are moderators selected by arXiv? I asked a question on this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154792/how-to-become-an-arxiv-moderator